# Refresh php data in html page dynamically through ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have 2 divs: one is a data from php variable:

```
<div id="data"><?php echo "$strstr"?></div>
```

Second is the div for ajax request:

```
<div id="divButton">[CLICK ME]</div>
```

Here is js code:

```
$("#divButton").on("click", function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {simpledata:12345},
        success : function(data) { 
        if (data.code == 200) 
            console.log("Success!");
        else console.log("Error!");
        }
});
```

And finally php code:

```
<?php 
$strstr = "A"; 
if ($_POST) { 
    $strstr = $strstr."A"; 
}
?>
```

As you can see I need dynamic update of first div, by clicking on second div.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any error or just no output? Also, try echoing out `$strstr` variable

Comment: What issue you are facing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the value of $strstr variable by just updating the value of it in you if condition. You need to make an action in your ajax when return is success. Like this

```
$("#divButton").on("click", function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {simpledata:12345},
        success : function(data) { 
             $('#data').text(data)
        }
    });
});
```

And in your php if condition you must return a string like this

```
<?php 
  $strstr = "A"; 
  if ($_POST) { 
    $strstr = $strstr."A"; 

     echo json_encode($strstr );
  }
?>
```

Comment: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

Comment: but that's how you must do to change the data dynamically.

Comment: As long as you return string in your php code then it was all fine

Comment: now all works fine, I think, but there only two letters of 'A', when I want train of them after every click, i guess this issue becose initialization of $strstr at the first line of php file... There is some ways to memorize this variable?

Answer (score 0):

HTML code Should be

```
<div id="data"><?php echo "$strstr"?></div>

<div id="divButton">[CLICK ME]</div>
```

Ajax Call Code

```
$("#divButton").on("click", function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {simpledata:12345},
        success : function(data) { 
              $("#data").html(data);
        },
        error : function() { 
              console.log("Error!");
        }
});
```

test.php Code Should be

```
<?php 
$strstr = "A"; 
if ($_POST) { 
    $strstr = $strstr."A"; 
}
echo $strstr;
//It is advisable that do not close php tag
```